# Pivoting two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with creating pivot, but firstly here are all my data structure with sets: https://pastebin.com/LiLHAMqs

And I have to create sql to get data in this [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU6K8.png).

I have to use pivot.

I have problem with counting how many cats of one sex is in every group.

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT  "Banda","Plec", NVL(SZEFUNIO,0) as SZEFUNIO, NVL(BANDZIOR,0) AS BANDZIOR, NVL(LOWCZY,0) AS LOWCZY, NVL(LAPACZ,0) AS LAPACZ, NVL(KOT,0) AS KOT, NVL(MILUSIA,0) AS MILUSIA, NVL(DZIELCZY,0) AS DZIELCZY,
(NVL(SZEFUNIO,0) + NVL(BANDZIOR,0) + NVL(LOWCZY,0) + NVL(LAPACZ,0) + NVL(KOT,0) + NVL(MILUSIA,0) + NVL(DZIELCZY,0)) as Suma
FROM   (SELECT b.nazwa "Banda", funkcja "Funkcja", plec "Plec", przydzial_myszy "przydzial", NVL(myszy_extra,0) "myszy_extra"  FROM Kocury k 
join Bandy b on b.numer_bandy = k.nr_bandy
)
PIVOT
   (  sum("przydzial" + NVL("myszy_extra",0))
     for "Funkcja"
     in ('SZEFUNIO' as SZEFUNIO, 'BANDZIOR' AS BANDZIOR, 'LOWCZY' AS LOWCZY, 'LAPACZ' AS LAPACZ, 'KOT' AS KOT, 'MILUSIA' AS MILUSIA, 'DZIELCZY' AS DZIELCZY ))
     order by "Banda";
```

Comment: Your inserts would be more helpful if you provided CREATE TABLE statements as well. (Please edit your post to add them at the top.)

Comment: @mathguy edited

Comment: You seem to be missing the FUNKCJE table and data. It seems to be important to your problem; if I am not mistaken, the columns of the pivoted table correspond to the different "funkcja" values. IMPORTANT QUESTION: are all the "funkcja" values known AHEAD OF TIME, without inspecting that "missing table" first? If not, then what you are asking for is dynamic pivoting, which is generally a bad practice to begin with, and may require skills you don't have.

Comment: @mathguy I add all my database structure (all create table and all insetion), I think it isn't a dynamic pivoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `count over partition` and indicate the name (`nazwa`) and the genre (`plec`), like this:

```
SELECT "Banda",
       "Plec",
       "Ile",
       NVL(SZEFUNIO, 0) as SZEFUNIO,
       NVL(BANDZIOR, 0) AS BANDZIOR,
       NVL(LOWCZY, 0) AS LOWCZY,
       NVL(LAPACZ, 0) AS LAPACZ,
       NVL(KOT, 0) AS KOT,
       NVL(MILUSIA, 0) AS MILUSIA,
       NVL(DZIELCZY, 0) AS DZIELCZY,
       (NVL(SZEFUNIO, 0) + NVL(BANDZIOR, 0) + NVL(LOWCZY, 0) +
       NVL(LAPACZ, 0) + NVL(KOT, 0) + NVL(MILUSIA, 0) + NVL(DZIELCZY, 0)) as Suma
  FROM (SELECT b.nazwa "Banda",
               count(*) over (partition by b.nazwa, k.plec) as "Ile",
               funkcja "Funkcja",
               plec "Plec",
               przydzial_myszy "przydzial",
               NVL(myszy_extra, 0) "myszy_extra"
          FROM Kocury k
          join Bandy b
            on b.numer_bandy = k.nr_bandy)
PIVOT(sum("przydzial" + NVL("myszy_extra", 0))
   for "Funkcja" in('SZEFUNIO' as SZEFUNIO,
                    'BANDZIOR' AS BANDZIOR,
                    'LOWCZY' AS LOWCZY,
                    'LAPACZ' AS LAPACZ,
                    'KOT' AS KOT,
                    'MILUSIA' AS MILUSIA,
                    'DZIELCZY' AS DZIELCZY))
 order by "Banda", "Ile";
```